# Archiving custom post content?

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

Last year, I built a movie festival website using "movie" as a custom post type.

Now that the festival is over and we're getting ready for next year, how would I archive that content so that I can start adding movies for the coming festival?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a category for that custom type with the year number . So old movies will been archived into a category of 2010 , and newer one into a category of 2011.
Also it will allow an easy way for your users to view and figure what year is a movie from.